# How to use go module as dependency in go dep project?

Tags: go, dependency-management, package-managers, go-modules, godeps

I have Go [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) project. I want to use go module as dependency. For example. I need this one https://github.com/pion/webrtc.

So, I try to declare the dependency like this, in **Gopkg.toml**:

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/pion/webrtc"
  revision = "6a0b7020b1724dcb302ddfadab0c80fabc144c97"
```

When I do `dep ensure`, I got errors:

```
Solving failure: No versions of github.com/pion/webrtc met constraints:
        6a0b7020b1724dcb302ddfadab0c80fabc144c97: "github.com/pion/webrtc" imports "github.com/pion/webrtc/v2/pkg/rtcerr", which con
tains malformed code: no package exists at "github.com/pion/webrtc/v2/pkg/rtcerr"
        v2.0.14: Could not introduce github.com/pion/webrtc@v2.0.14, as it is not allowed by constraint 6a0b7020b1724dcb302ddfadab0c
80fabc144c97 from project ***.
        v2.0.13: Could not introduce github.com/pion/webrtc@v2.0.13, as it is not allowed by constraint 6a0b7020b1724dcb302ddfadab0c
80fabc144c97 from project ***.
```

It seems, that the problem is connected with *2 version* of library. When it was *1*, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using Pion :)

We had the same [issue](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/issues/493) opened on Pion WebRTC issue tracker. There is a [PR](https://github.com/golang/dep/pull/1963) to fix dep for this case.

If possible I would switch to modules though, but in the meantime hopefully using this patched version of dep should help!